# Por que o fadeIn do jQuery não funciona se o elemento possui opacidade zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um elemento com opacidade zero definida via JavaScript. Na prática, isso equivale a:

```html
<div style="opacity: 0"></div>
```

Minha intenção é utilizar o jQuery para fazer um efeito de *fade-in* no elemento. Tentei o seguinte:

```js
$('div').fadeIn();
```

<sup>[Demonstração no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qFaz5/)</sup>

Porém, o elemento continua com opacidade zero, e nunca fica visível. Sei que consigo [contornar o problema](http://jsfiddle.net/bkc5R/) utilizando o [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) [ou `display: none`](http://jsfiddle.net/ec7Cw/) , mas por que o [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) não funciona?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O objetivo do [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) não é "animar a opacidade do elemento", e sim fazer a transição de invisível para visível. Por "invisível" me refiro a `display: none`. A animação da opacidade é apenas um artifício para que o elemento parta da opacidade `0` (*de facto* invisível) até sua opacidade atual (seja ela qual for).

Como [esse exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/qFaz5/1/) mostra, um elemento inicialmente escondido vai se tornar "visível" (i.e. ocupar espaço na tela) quando você usar `fadeIn`. Mas sua opacidade final será aquela que ele possui de fato (ou seja, `0`). ([outro exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/qFaz5/2/), mostrando que a transição de fato ocorre, mas não vai até o `1`)

Se você quer um método que lhe permita escolher uma opacidade final - independentemente daquela do elemento - experimente [`fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/).

```javascript
$("div").fadeTo(2000, 1); // tempo, opacidade final, callback
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/qFaz5/3/). Note que, ainda que o elemento não esteja inicialmente invisível (i.e. sem o `display: none`), a transição da opacidade é realizada normalmente.

Comment: Entendi. A pegadinha é que o efeito do fade só é possível por meio da animação da opacidade. Isso me levou a pensar que o papel do `fadeIn` seria animar a opacidade até 1.

Answer (score 9):

O jQuery não faz fade à `opacity`, [**exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/39xXa/3/)

Encontrei uma [`resposta interessante`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6045814/2256325) <sup>(em Inglês)</sup> que fala sobre isto. E curiosamente  o jQuery [**considera**](http://jsfiddle.net/39xXa/2/) `opacity:0` como não escondido!

```
<div style="opacity: 0"></div>
console.log($('div').is(':hidden')); //false
```

O fade aplica-se à propriedade display. Para fazer um fade à opacidade, então a solução é:

- usar [**.animate()**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) como você referiu
- ou usando o [**.fadeTo()**](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/) que é pensado para a opacidade, por [**exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yZeux/1/): `$('div').fadeTo(2000, 1);`

Isto foi pelos vistos [**discutido no passado**](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9336) mas acabou por não ser alterado.

Comment: Obrigado Sergio. Veja meu comentário na resposta do mgibsonbr, lá explico o que me confundiu.

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu também deparei com este problema à uns tempos e curiosamente porque o __[.fade('in')](http://jsfiddle.net/6hxBC/)__ do Mootools tem o problema invertido. Faz um fade à opacity e não ao display.